# Javascript: How do I target with event.target an outer div so called Margin?

Tags: javascript

I got an element that i drag over a list of elements.
I already got the list of nodes. All my nodes have margins.

When I drag over an elements margin or that element( that node) I would like to trigger an alert.

If I right click between elements that have margin, it picks up the parent element. So the way I understand is to that I can locate the outer div?

Here a check that I do to check if I drag over a list and I am dragging over the node and it works but I can seem to trigger if I drag over the elements margin.

I am writing this in pure javascript, not a fan of Jquery or external libraries.

```
 if (listItemNode.parentNode == listNode && listItemNode != placeholderNode) {
            // If the mouse pointer is in the upper half of the list item element,
            // we position the placeholder before the list item, otherwise after it.
            var rect = listItemNode.getBoundingClientRect();
            if (listSettings.horizontal) {
                console.log( rect.left);
              var isFirstHalf = event.clientX < rect.left + rect.width / 2;

            } else {
              var isFirstHalf = event.clientY < rect.top + rect.height / 2;
            }
            listNode.insertBefore(placeholderNode,
                isFirstHalf ? listItemNode : listItemNode.nextSibling);


}
```

Comment: Adjust your HTML and CSS so you can use the mouseleave event?

Comment: mouse enter is not tracked , so I can use mouse leave. I I don't know when I enter that element outter div, or when I enter on top of the margin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An element's margin is not really a part of the element, its the gap between elements. Therefore, events bound to an element will not be triggered by it's margin. Replace the margin with padding or border to get the results you want.
one thing that might work is to wrap your elements with the margins with other elements and define the wrappers as your droppables. that way they will be behind the margin and could trigger the event

Comment: I need the margin, must be a way to calculate if the user is on the margin

Comment: Maybe there is, I can theoretically think of several ways which would be very complicated, hard to develop and maintain and might have their own problems. Either way, that contradicts the way margin works, and AFAIK the idea behind margin. why do you need the margin and not the border, which can give similar visual result but is in fact a part of the element?

Comment: Thought of one way that is less difficult, you could wrap your elements with the margins with other elements and define the wrappers as your droppables. that way they will be behind the margin and could trigger the event